# Asp.Net Core 2 SignalR Ubuntu Xamarin Android

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-2.0

I have deployed Asp.Net Core 2 website on ubuntu with Nginx as a reverse proxy. The website works but SignalR doesn't. Same build work locally in IIS-Express. Getting following error in logs,
Terminating Long Polling connection by sending 204 response.

Following nginx configuration I am using,

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I am accessing the server from Xamarin Android. 
What can be the issue? Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade"`;

Comment: Thanks. If I do this, my POST-APIs doesn't work. I will try again though.

Comment: You may need it on a specific URL location and not the whole `/`

Comment: Ok. Yeah. Will try Thanks.

Comment: Works by adding "Upgrade" for the particular location. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should change you config to add additional path which needs the Upgrade header

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /socket/path/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```